# Can't connect to my samba share from the USA

Tags: ubuntu, samba

Running the standard ubuntu samba package. I can connect to it from Australia just fine from any computer, but whenever I'm in the USA it just times out. Hosting on Amazon EC2. Any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: Tried from both windows and mac in the USA on multiple computers. Doesn't work, but multiple computers/OSs work just fine in AUS.

Comment: Maybe the problem is simply the distance, the high latency you get connecting to a server halfway around the world?

Comment: Some ISPs block SMB traffic, especially on residential connections. A quick `nmap` should help determine if this is the cause.

Comment: @MichaelHampton this was it. Was getting filtered by ISPs. Thanks for the help :)